# Removing delimiters from a date/time string

Tags: regex, perl, timestamp

I want to take this

```
Code:
2010-12-21 20:00:00
```

and make it look like this:

```
Code:
20101221200000
```

This is the last thing I tried

```
Code:
#!/usr/bin/perl  -w
use strict;
my ($teststring) = '2010-12-21 20:00:00';
my $result =  " ";
print "$teststring\n";
$teststring =~ "/(d\{4\})(d\{3\})(d\{3\})(d\{3\})(d\{3\})(d\{3\})/$result";
        { 
    print "$_\n";
    print "$result\n";
        print "$teststring\n";
    }
```

And it produced this:

```
Code:
nathan@debian:~/Desktop$ ./ptest
2010-12-21 20:00:00
Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at ./ptest line 8.


2010-12-21 20:00:00
nathan@debian:~/Desktop$
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, here is the problem with your code:

```
$teststring =~ "/(d\{4\})(d\{3\})(d\{3\})(d\{3\})(d\{3\})(d\{3\})/$result";
```

You want to use `=~` with the substitution operator `s///`. That is, the right hand side should not be a plain string, but `s/pattern/replacement/`.

In the pattern part, `\d` would denote a digit. However, `\d` includes all sorts characters that are in the Unicode digit class, so it is safer to use the character class `[0-9]` if that's what you want to match against. `[0-9]{4}` would mean match characters `0` through `9` four times. Note that you should not escape the curly brackets `{` and `}`.

The parentheses `(` and `)` define capture groups. In the replacement part, you want to keep the stuff you captured, and ignore the stuff you did not.

In addition, I am assuming these timestamps occur in other input, and you do not want to accidentally replace stuff you did not mean to (by blindly removing all non-digits).

Below, I use the `/x` modifier for the `s///` operator so I can format the `pattern` more clearly using white-space.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s{
        ^
        ([0-9]{4})-
        ([0-9]{2})-
        ([0-9]{2})[ ]
        ([0-9]{2}):
        ([0-9]{2}):
        ([0-9]{2})
    }{$1$2$3$4$5$6}x;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Code:
2010-12-21 20:00:00
```

or, using named capture groups introduced in `5.10` can make the whole thing slightly more readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s{
        ^
        ( ?<year>  [0-9]{4} ) -
        ( ?<month> [0-9]{2} ) -
        ( ?<day>   [0-9]{2} ) [ ]
        ( ?<hour>  [0-9]{2} ) :
        ( ?<min>   [0-9]{2} ) :
        ( ?<sec>   [0-9]{2} )
    }
    {
        local $";
        "@+{qw(year month day hour min sec)}"
    }ex;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Code:
2010-12-21 20:00:00
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular expression to replace all non-digits (`[^\d]` or `[\D]`) with the empty string:

```
$ perl -e '$_ = "2010-12-21 20:00:00"; s/[\D]//g; print $_;'
20101221200000
```

Comment: yeah, like that. I was writing R-style again.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just remove anything that's not a digit?

```
s/[^\d]//g
```

in sed format, can't remember the perl.

Answer (score 0):

```
($result = $teststring) =~ y/0-9//cd;
```